# Named routes with two $param(s) - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use two params with a named route through a controller, but receive an error when loading the view

**Route**

```
Route::get('agendarVehiculo/{idvehiculo}/{idcita}', array('as' => 'agendarVehiculo', 'uses' => 'AgendamientosController@addAgendaCitaVehiculo'));
```

**View**

```
<td>
<a href="{{ route('agendarCitaPaciente', [$paciente->id, $cita->id ] }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"> Agendar</i></a>
</td>
```

**Error**

```
syntax error, unexpected '['
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your PHP 5.4+? If not, you'll have to:

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('agendarCitaPaciente', array($paciente->id, $cita->id)) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 
       <i class="fa fa-calendar"> Agendar</i>
    </a>
</td>
```

As pointed by @SumanBogati, you also have a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`[$paciente->id, $cita->id ]`

To

`array($paciente->id, $cita->id)`

It looks like you're using a PHP version that doesn't support the newer method of defining arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to write colosing parenthesis `)` on this

```
<a href="{{ route('agendarCitaPaciente', [$paciente->id, $cita->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"> Agendar</i></a>
//--------------------------------------missing parenthesis here----^
```